# Python regex match groups have more than expected object

Tags: python, regex

I am using re.search to parse a line for 3 separate pieces of data. (date temperature and pressure) The line looks like this.

```
line= "2015-10-08-22-50   27.3   1015.03"
```

I want to use pattern matching so that I can be very robust against malformed lines. Using split has failed for that reason.

I built following re.

```
m= re.search("^(2\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d+.\d+)\s+(\d+.\d+)$", line)
```

The parsing is fine however the match groups surprised me.

```
>>> m.groups(1)
('2015-10-08-23-00', '27.3', '1014.99')
>>> m.groups(2)
('2015-10-08-23-00', '27.3', '1014.99')
>>> m.groups(3)
('2015-10-08-23-00', '27.3', '1014.99')
```

I (naively) had expected.

```
>>> m.groups(1)
('2015-10-08-23-00')
>>> m.groups(2)
('27.3')
>>> m.groups(3)
('1014.99')
```

For now I work around this by using indices.

```
dt= m.groups(1)[0]
t = m.groups(2)[1]
p = m.groups(3)[2]
```

I conclude that the re that I believed was OK must be flawed or not as clean as possible.

What's missing?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
m.groups(1)
```

I think you want:

```
m.groups()[0]
```

The parameter to groups() is a default value, not a position in the tuple it returns. So you don't need to pass it anything. You do need to index the tuple it returns.

```
help(m.groups)
Help on built-in function groups:

groups(...)
    groups([default=None]) -> tuple.

    Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1.
    The default argument is used for groups
    that did not participate in the match
```

Answer (score 3):

```
to capture parenthesized subgroup
use group, not groups

print(m.group(1))

2015-10-08-22-50

print(m.group(2))
27.3

print(m.group(3))
1015.03

print(m.group(1,3))

('2015-10-08-22-50', '1015.03')
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `m.groups()` is not which capture group to return. It's an optional default value to use for any capture groups that didn't match anything. Either way, the function returns a list containing all the capture groups, and you have to index it to get a particular one.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your pattern.

You could use named groups to clarify:

```
>>> pat=re.compile(r"""^(?P<date>2\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+
...                     (?P<temp>\d+.\d+)\s+
...                     (?P<pres>\d+.\d+)$""", re.X)
>>> line= "2015-10-08-22-50   27.3   1015.03"
>>> m=pat.search(line)
```

Which then produces a dictionary:

```
>>> m.groupdict()
{'date': '2015-10-08-22-50', 'temp': '27.3', 'pres': '1015.03'}
>>> m.group('date')
'2015-10-08-22-50'
>>> m.group('temp')
'27.3'
```

But can also be accessed as usual:

```
>>> m.group(1)
'2015-10-08-22-50'
>>> m.group(2)
'27.3'
```

Or index the tuple returned by `groups()` but I don't think that is very clear (as you seem to have discovered...)

```
>>> m.groups()[2]
'1015.03'
```

If you use named groups, you get the best of all worlds.